# Retain Drop Down Value Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using entity type form field which displays and persists perfectly however, when I edit the form it does not auto-selects the value.

```
Form: $builder->add('type', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Activity',
                'empty_value' => 'Please select'
            ))

Controller:
$activity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Activity')->findOne($updateId);
$form = $this->createForm(new ActivityType(), $activity);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

On the other hand if I simply use static drop down list it works:

```
Working Code:

->add('type', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        1=>"A",
                        2=>"B",
                        3=>"C",
                        4=>"D",
                    ),
                    "empty_value"=>"Please Select",
                    'required' => false
                ))
```

Comment: hmm, the question is a little confusing. Do you mean that when you go to edit the entity the form is for, it doesn't preselect the value of the field from the database in the field on the form?

Comment: You are loading the entity from the database before displaying it, aren't you? You don't show where $activity is being created.

Comment: Ah, try putting a name space on the class you pass into the builder method .. ie.. ... 'class' => 'Bundle:Activity',